# Ubuntu , mysqldump

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

mysqldump -u roman -p car > car_backup.sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u roman -p car > car_backup.sql' at line 1
where error ?

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` is a CLI application. You don't type it into an SQL query, you type it at the command line.

Comment: where should I enter this request?

Comment: I enter this request in the command line